# How do I close a GNOME terminal by giving a command in another terminal in linux?

Tags: gnome-terminal

I have opened a gnome terminal as a new different window terminal using the gnome command in Linux. Now what I want is that I want to close only that gnome terminal by giving a certain command in the other terminal. 
I had tried a command as 'kill PID', but with that both the terminals are closed.
Can anyone help me with how to close only the gnome terminal by writing command in the other terminal??

Answer (score 0):

Use "xdotool" to send alt+F4 to the target window. Replace zeros with your windowID:

```
xdotool windowactivate --sync 00000000 key --clearmodifiers alt+F4
```

You can use "xdotool search" to get the windowID. Insert between quotes the terminal title:

```
xdotool search --name "text_to_search"
```

Joining all commands:

```
xdotool windowactivate --sync $(xdotool search --name "text_to_search") key --clearmodifiers alt+F4
```

If you need, add "--delay 100" to get a better performance.

To install "xdotool" type:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```